# change computed based on another computed in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have this in vue 3. I need to change the title using the prop id if is 0 should be 'New' else 'Details' based on another computed property that I have editMode

```
setup(props) {
  const {id} = toRefs(props)
  const editMode = computed(() => {
    return id.value !== 0
  })
  const title = computed(() => {
    return editMode ? 'Details' : 'New'
  })
}
```

the problem is when editMode is false the title is not changing ..... remains 'Details' all the time.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to alter `editMode` to `editMode.value` inside title compute, given `editMode` also belongs to Ref type.

```
const title = computed(() => {
  return editMode.value ? 'Details' : 'New'
})
```

This should simply solve your problem.

Also try `console.log(typeof id.value)` to ensure String `'0'` and Number `0` are not mixed up.

Comment: yup .... forgot the value :-)